# Check if user given input exists as a key on a type, if true, assign user value to type key

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to add a CLI command where a user can update a config file. The config file has a type of:

```js
export type ConfigFile = {
    accessToken: string,
    refreshToken: string,
    storageKey: string,
    adminKey: string
}
```

In my CLI command the user can pass in a key and value but I don't know the best way to programmatically check if a key exists and if so assign the value. Here's what I have so far:

```js
cli
    .command("config:set")
    .description("Set CLI configuration")
    .requiredOption("-k, --key <key>", "config property key")
    .requiredOption("-v, --value <value>", "config property value")
    .action((flags: {key: string, value: string}) => {

        const cfg: ConfigFile = client.config().read();

        if (flags.key === "accessToken") cfg.accessToken = flags.value;
        if (flags.key === "refreshToken") cfg.refreshToken = flags.value;
        if (flags.key === "storageKey") cfg.storageKey = flags.value;
        if (flags.key === "adminKey") cfg.adminKey = flags.value;

    });
```

> Above code slightly modified for brevity/clarity

The above works but now I have to update the code in two places whenever the `ConfigFile` type changes.

I tried using what I would do in vanilla JS but type script doesn't like it:

```js
for (let key in cfg) {
   if (key === flags.key) cfg[key] = flags.value;
}
```

Comment: Why not `cfg[flags.key] = flags.value;` here? If you get errors (which you probably will) about the key being the wrong type, you can either cast the key to the correct type or change the type of `cfg` to a record.

Comment: @hhearts when trying the above I get `TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'ConfigFile'.   No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'ConfigFile'.`

Answer (score 0):

I followed the above suggestion from @hhearts and set the type to a record

```js
const cfg: Record<string, string> = client.config().read();

// returns a blank object of the type
if (flags.key in client.config().new()) {
    cfg[flags.key] = flags.value;
}
else {
    console.error(`${flags.key} is not a valid config file property`)
}
```